# Can accordions to have rounded corners?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, slds, slds-styling-hooks

I have tried `CSS`'s `border-radius` and [SLDS hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/accordion/) on `lightning-accordion` and `lightning-accordion-section`, but I am unable to achieve rounded corners on it. I have changed the color to lightgray so I can see the difference when changing rem and px. Are rounded corners possible on either of these reference components?

slds hooks attempted:

```
Sizing   --slds-c-accordion-sizing-border
Spacing  --slds-c-accordion-section-spacing-block-end
         --slds-c-accordion-section-spacing-block-start
         --slds-c-accordion-section-spacing-inline-end
         --slds-c-accordion-section-spacing-inline-start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. CSS hooks are defined something like this:

```
:host {
  --slds-c-accordion-sizing-border: 3px;
}
.some-element {
  border-size: var(--slds-c-accordion-sizing-border);
}
```

They are written specific enough that you can't just throw a border-radius in there and expect it to work. You are allowed to use the properties only as they are designed to be used.

Comment: ah okay got it, thought there was a possibility to get it to have that. thank you!

Comment: @TristanBerger && @sfdcfox - Is there any workaround that you are using to add the border-radius to the `accordion-section` ? I ran into the same issue today.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue as my accordion did not look like the standard one and solved it by using what is described here instead of accordion...

check expandableSection.html & expandableSection.js:
https://salesforcediaries.com/2022/07/26/reusable-expandable-collapsible-section-in-lightning-web-component/amp/